# Django: Multiple parameters in URLs reverse resolution without querystrings or captured parameters

Tags: django, url, parameters, reverse

Without using query strings (like ?case=/2/), nor captured parameters in the url conf (like ?P) (so they dont show up in the url),
is there a way to pass parameters to a view function when using URLs reverse resolution?

Hopefully an example will clarify my question:

With captured parameters I could do:

views.py
...
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('videos:show_details', args=[video.id]))

urls.py
...
url(r'^club/(?P\d+)/$',views.details, name='show_details'),
...

But what if the view details needs / accepts more parameters, for example:

def details (request, video_id, director='', show_all=True):

And we dont want them to show up in the url?

Any way of using args or kwargs without them being in the url?

Im sure Im missing something trivial here :S

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you mean, but you can pass extra arguments to the url pattern. This allows multiple urls that point to the same view to use different arguments:

```
url(r'^club/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.details, kwargs={'show_all': False}, name='show_details')
```

Comment: Sorry, my question is horribly and terribly formulated :( Thanks for the answer! What if the argument in kwargs is something generated dynamically and we dont know what the value will be? (like, an email, telephone number)? How would one write the url pattern?

Comment: @AndyKameruchi Where would that email/telephone number come from? This method is not suited for dynamic arguments. If you want to use a redirect like in your question, the only way to pass in dynamic arguments is to actually pass them in through a url parameter or a query string.

Comment: Thanks! Which method would be appropriated for redirecting and passing dynamic arguments? The email or telephone number  would come from a table on the DB, but that table is filled by users. Hope this makes sense.